# Simple help on Gervill with SF2 soundbank

Tags: java, gervill

I have download [Grevill](https://gervill.dev.java.net/) gervill.jar and with my existing code follow from:
http://www.jsresources.org/examples/MidiPlayer.html

Could anyone spare a little effort to write a tutorial on loading  SF2 soundbank? I would cry without a tutorial on the web.

Comment: -1 Voted to close.  Not a real question.  Do you have a specific question?  This isn't the appropriate place to request someone to write a tutorial.

Comment: Well, do you have a better idea where to ask then?

Comment: @Erick know how to vote yet doesn't know how to solve a simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
new SF2Soundbank(new FileInputStream(new File("sb.sf2")));
```

Then you just load all the instruments in the synthesizer.

Answer (score 0):

**Do some research.**

If you want to learn how this code works, download it and try it.  Generate javadoc API reference docs from the source.  Try to figure it out.  If you have problems getting it to work, post another question like this, but include specific details of the problem you are having.

You'll get a much better response this way.  Stack Overflow is not someplace to find someone to do your research work for you.

Comment: The problem is, lack of tutorials and docs. How about try to code it yourself and see if you know how? And how many applications have used Gervill? As far as I know there is only one or two and the code are in OO style. There is only a tiny fraction of music programmers here which is not good. Please tell me where should I asked? Java engineer?